# How can I parse bad json in php?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse the json below, but I can't, I keep getting empty result.

Here is the json:

```
$response = '{"Status":1,"CodigoErro":null,"SKYException":"","ResultString":"{\"DadosBasicos\":{\"NomeCompleto\":null,\"Nome\":null,\"Sobrenome\":null,\"DataNascimento\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"EstadoCivil\":null,\"Login\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com.br\",\"Sexo\":0,\"CPF_CNPJ\":\"09414954775\",\"IdPerfilFaturamento\":null,\"IdConta\":\"13879034\",\"Assinaturas\":[{\"Id\":\"62606412\",\"ParentId\":null,\"Email\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com.br\",\"DNA\":\"010000000001001000000010000000001000000000000000001000000010000000000001000000000000000010110001111101000000001000000001000000000111101000000100000101000001000011111111111110000000000000000000011000000010101011101111110100000000111110101101111100010000000000011011111111011010011011100011111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111110101111111111111011110100000011111111111111111111000\",\"StatusAssinatura\":1,\"ValorEmAberto\":null,\"CEP\":\"27540440\",\"TipoAssinatura\":0,\"ModoEntrega\":0,\"Produtos\":[],\"Equipamentos\":[],\"IlhaMaster\":false,\"Tier1\":true,\"PrincipalId\":\"062606412\",\"Enderecos\":null,\"Telefones\":null,\"TipoOrganizacao\":0,\"PassoRegua\":null,\"GeoCode\":\"BRL04100\",\"Fidelizado\":false,\"PossuiInteratividadePrePago\":false,\"PossuiSKYDigitalCortesia\":false,\"PossuiCanaisCortesiaLivre\":false,\"DataAtivacao\":\"2011-01-25T00:00:00\",\"DataFidelizacao\":\"2012-01-25T00:00:00\",\"TipoCliente\":\"F\",\"Segmento\":null,\"Pacote\":null,\"GloboCongelada\":[],\"ListaDeCanais\":[],\"CodigoTipoAssinatura\":null,\"CanceladoAteSeisMeses\":false,\"DataCancelamento\":null}]},\"DadosComplementares\":null}","Token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjcGZfY25waiI6IjA5NDE0OTU0Nzc1Iiwic2lnbmF0dXJlcyI6WyI2MjYwNjQxMiJdLCJpYXQiOjE1NDc5MTA4NDgsImV4cCI6MTU0Nzk5NzI0OH0.ho1V67cI4jZPXZ-DqnF-WzCRSKSY38uJuQs0tRXrdYM"}';
```

And here is what I have tried to do:

```
$json_bad = json_decode($response);
$json_002 = json_decode($json_bad->ResultString);

$email = $json_002->Login;
```

However, it doesn't work, I keep getting empty variable.

Comment: try this $json_bad = json_decode($response,true);
$json_002 = json_decode($json_bad->ResultString,true); $email = $json_002['Login'];

Comment: If you are so sure that your data is invalid JSON then `json_decode()` is not the right tool because it cannot parse invalid JSON. But there doesn't seem to be anything wrong in your data.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `$json_002` contain multilevel with value `DadosBasicos`

So, you can access it in two ways:

1. Using `stdClass` object:

   ```
    $json_bad = json_decode($response);
    $json_002 = json_decode($json_bad->ResultString);

    $email = $json_002->DadosBasicos->Login;
   ```
2. Using Array :

   ```
    $json_bad = json_decode($response,true);
    $json_002 = json_decode($json_bad['ResultString'],true);

    $email = $json_002['DadosBasicos']['Login'];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing 1 level in the second JSON decoded data...

```
{"DadosBasicos":{"NomeCompl...
```

So your email address is actually in

```
$email = $json_002->DadosBasicos->Login;
```